# Is there a significant difference between deleting a record and deleting data on the record but not the record itself?

Tags: delete, data-storage, storage-limit, storage

From a storage perspective, is there a significant difference between deleting a record vs. deleting data from fields on the record but keeping the data itself?

Our org has a lot of Cases and custom objects that have relations to Contacts. In some cases, however, when a Contact is no longer a client, we have some sensitive information we'd like to remove from our org. However, simply deleting the record would potentially orphan those related records, so we'd much rather keep the Contact around and delete the sensitive information. I have been asked if keeping these inactive Contacts around could lead to storage issues on down the line, even if we wipe all the fields except for a few on the Contact, and I genuinely don't know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every record takes up the exact same storage based on its type. [For most records](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383664&type=1), this is 2kb per record. If you erase every single field value, but don't delete the record itself, it will still use the same 2kb. Note that each type of record uses storage. A contact with 100 cases uses a total of 204kb, 200kb for the cases, 2kb for the contact, and 2kb for the account. Also note that files use separate storage, and is 1:1 with regards to the size of the file.

Comment: your link is a copy-paste error: `https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_http_callout.htm&type=5`

Comment: Yeah, the comment is very helpful but is this the URL you intended to link?

Comment: @d-fws No, it wasn't the link I wanted. Not sure how that even got into my clipboard, lol. I've edited the link.